# jenkins not able to find java test class in pom.xml

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, pom.xml

Below is the `pom.xml` code I have used for linking to test java file.  I am giving jenkins this `pom.xml` path to use, but jenkins' console output is still showing:

> unable to load main class

```
<build>
    <directory>C:/Users/etuslik/IdeaProjects/gmail-webui-test/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>C:/Users/etuslik/IdeaProjects/gmail-webui-test/classes</outputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>C:/Users/etuslik/IdeaProjects/gmail-webui-test/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <!-- TODO: MNG-3731 maven-plugin-tools-api < 2.4.4 expect this to be relative... -->
    <testSourceDirectory>C:/Users/etuslik/IdeaProjects/gmail-webui-test/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>C:/Users/etuslik/IdeaProjects/gmail-webui-test/Test/java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. 
1. To include any specific java file

```
  <includes>
        <include>Sample.java</include>
  </includes>
```

2. To include packages

```
  <includes>
        <include>my.package.*, my.package2.*</include>
  </includes>
```